# renewal of letsencrypt certificate fails

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm using debain jessie, certbot version 0.9.3-1~bpo8+2. Since last two days I've been started getting this error while renewing certificates for my site.

```
Could not bind TCP port 443 because it is already in use by another process on
this system (such as a web server). Please stop the program in question and then
try again.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/www.testsite.com.conf produced an unexpected error: object of type 'NoneType' has no len(). Skipping.
```

What should I do ? I'm not much familiar with Letsencrypt. Anybody please shade light on this ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just stop your webserver and run the same again. If you are using nginx use `sudo service nginx stop`

Comment: Not working at all

Answer (score 11):

I haven't found a way to do this with "zero downtime", but you can auto stop/start nginx with hooks so you can handle renewals with cron:

```
certbot renew --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Stopping the server manually and restarting makes the auto renewal process useless. This works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Not working at all

Answer (score -1):

I am apache2 lover, here is solution

> certbot renew --cert-name www.snippetbucket.com  --pre-hook
>   "service apache2 stop" --post-hook "service apache2 start"

Makes more simple and works 100%.

Now, with all domain reference on apache hosted server, automated process.

> certbot renew --pre-hook
>   "service apache2 stop" --post-hook "service apache2 start"

Advice: In case automated not works, just schedule renew process in advance according server low traffic.

Comment: Not working at all

Comment: @FedericoSchiocchet have't you share anything of try or cause, just wrote not working directly, how someone can helps you !